# Controller returning un rendered view

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am facing an issue with my controllers `refs` and the returned object being invalid. And by invalid it returning me an object that says it has not been rendered even though i am in the process of using it.

In my controller I have a ref defined as the following.

```
refs : [ {
        ref : 'selectDeltaView',
        selector : '[itemId=selectDeltaView]'
    }]
```

and later in my controller I access this view using the created accessor

`this.getSelectDeltaView()`

What is strange is that the first time this view is presented, inside of an `Ext.Window` it works just fine. However, on the second launch the view I get back is not rendered.

`this.getSeletDeltaView().rendered === false`

Reading the documentation over at Sencha it seems that this simply passes my selector to the `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` function. However, if I call `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=selectDeltaView]')` I get an array with a single element of which rendered is true.

Am i missing something? Why is my controllers reference returning me invalid data.

**Update**

Some additional details not mentioned in the original post. My initial assumption was that my view was not being destroyed. However, I have log statements in my `ondestory` and `beforedestory` events and can confirm that on closing the window my view is being destroyed.

What is the most confusing is that if refs simply use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query`, why does `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` only return one view when the window is re-opened and it returns the correct view. I understand from the question below that refs will catch the view, but that view no longer exist.. or shouldn't.. If the view is destroyed, can I force the controller to clear its catch?

Comment: If a cached view no longer exists, the `refs` will not return it, but find the new view. I think there is something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

The controllers reference is cached after the first evaluation.

What happens is this:

- You open your view a first time.
- `getSeletDeltaView()` finds that view, and stores a reference to it in the reference lookup cache.
- You close the view, but you do not destroy it completely.
- You open the view a second time, but it is a different instance.
- `getSeletDeltaView()` finds the first view, that is no longer rendered, but still exists, because it was not destroyed. You cannot use this reference, because it point to the wrong view.

Solution:

Make sure to `destroy()` your view, when you hide it. You can also use `autoDestroy` as a property. Usually, `autoDestroy` is true by default.

Comment: I up voted your response because, this was exactly the path I took. However, on my `Ext.window.Window` i have `autoDestroy: true` and I have added log statements to my views `beforedestroy` and `ondestroy` and both are firing when I close the window.